# How to prove the Archimedean property?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

The archimedean property states that

$$\boxed{~\forall~ ~a,b\in \mathbb{Z}^+~ \exists ~n~|~na\geq b~}$$

I started with disproving ..

Suppose $\forall ~\{n,a,b\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^+ , \text{na < b}$

$\implies b-na >0$

$\text{As this holds true for all n} \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \text{ let n = x}$

$\implies b-xa>0$

$\implies b-(x+1)a > 0\quad or\quad b-xa-a<0$

$b-ma>b-ma-a$

I dont know how to proceed any further. If i cancel b-ma, i get nothing but that a is positive. so how do we prove it. and also is there any false statement in my proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $n = b$? Then $na = ba \geq b$.

Comment: That is in fact nice. But how do ew conclude in the end. Like in your case .. it will be $b > ba$. Then how we conclude after that? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Tim Krul : You want to prove, that for all $a,b$ there is such an $n$. We proved this by explicitly by defining such an $n$ for all $a,b$ and showing, that it satisfies $na\geq b$. That is all.

Comment: if $a,b \in Z^+$ then $\frac{b}{a} \in Q $ so ,exist $m$ such that $m=\left \lfloor  \frac{b}{a}\right \rfloor$ $$m+1>m\\m+1>\frac{b}{a}\\$$now let $\exists n \in Z^+|n>m+1$

Comment: @columbus8myhw Thanks i got that!

Answer (score 2):

The classical proof start from the lemma:

> The set $\mathbb{N}$ of positive integers $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2,
> > \cdots\}$ is not bounded from above.

That can be proved by Peano axioms.

Now: $na\ge b$ is equivalent to : $n\ge \dfrac{b}{a}$ and, if such an $n$ does not exists than $n<\dfrac{b}{a}$ for all integers $n$ and this contradicts the lemma.

Comment: are there any good book in which we get such structure approach to proof? Thanks.